# Efficient way to check for data tables in a data set

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, dataset

```
public void Method1()
{
  Datatable dt1 = new DataTable();
  Datatable dt2 = new DataTable();
  Datatable dt3 = new DataTable();

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{       
         if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
         if (ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
              dt2 = ds.Tables[1];
          if (ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 0)
              dt3 = ds.Tables[2];              
}
}
```

In the code above is there a better way to check for exact number of tables in the dataset "ds", whenever ds has three tables there is no issue but if it has one table it fails on second if condition and throws an exception Cannot find Table1. Any pointers on checking if that tables exists or not.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use loop to loop thru all the tables in the dataset. You want be able to use different variables like  dt1, dt2 etc though.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  In the above code you can see am using different variables. can you share a sample.

Comment: If you want to use different variables, the solution for that would be dirty. Can you explain the use case where you need this kind of code, then appropriate solution can be provided where you don't need to use different variables and still achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. For example you can do the following, if you still want three DataTable objects:

```
public void Method1()
{
    DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 ? ds.Tables[0] : new DataTable();
    DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables.Count > 1 && ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0 ? ds.Tables[1] : new DataTable();
    DataTable dt3 = ds.Tables.Count > 2 && ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 0 ? ds.Tables[2] : new DataTable();
}
```

A more dynamic way would be to store all tables in a list like this:

```
public void Method1()
{
    List<DataTable> dataTables = new List<DataTable>();

    foreach (DataTable dataTable in ds.Tables)
    {
        if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0) dataTables.Add(dataTable);
    }

}
```

or by using Linq

```
public void Method2()
{
    List<DataTable> dataTables = ds.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Where(dataTable => dataTable.Rows.Count > 0).ToList();
}
```